# What git commit message that fixes bad code?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit

I commited and pushed my code and then realized that the code was not written well. What should I write as a commit message that fix/ clean up that code?

just "fix bad code"?

Comment: Does "not written well" mean it worked but it was poorly designed? Or it had bugs?

Comment: Write a proper commit message like any other one: briefly say what you're doing and, more importantly, *why*.  In your case, what made the earlier code bad?  Why is your new commit an improvement?

Comment: it worked but it was poorly designed

Answer (score 4):

Think about someone looking at your change five years from now. They can see *what* you did, but they don't know *why*. Your commit message explains the *why*, and the context of what you did to this person (who may be you).

Your commits should be small enough that you can provide a summary of what you did.

Use [Semantic Commit Messages](https://sparkbox.com/foundry/semantic_commit_messages) to provide a general structure.

`fix` would be for fixing a bug.

```
fix: Forgot to strip whitespace before handling user input
```

`refactor` would be for redesigning code.

```
refactor: Redesign the Frobniz system

Frobniz was too complicated, so I extracted it into
Frobniz::Parse and Frobniz::Push. Frobniz delegates to
these objects now.
```

Maybe you forgot to add documentation.

```
docs: adding documentation to Frobniz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your commit message as whatever you like, as long as it describes what the commit is doing.

Comment: I'm working on a big project, so I'd like to write a bit more information than, for example, "Fix bad code".  Any ideas what I could write there